# Eigen non constant MatrixReplacement for sparse solver

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3, mutability

I want to use matrix free sparse solvers with custom matrix-vector product object. Here is great example how to to it - https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__MatrixfreeSolverExample.html

But in this example custom matrix-product object should be constant due to generic_product_impl signature

```
template<typename Dest>
static void scaleAndAddTo(
    Dest& dst, 
    const MatrixReplacement& lhs, 
    const Rhs& rhs, 
    const Scalar& alpha)
```

In many my problems i need a lot of temporary buffers for each product call. It's pretty wise to allocate them once but i can't store them inside `MatrixReplacement` because it passed as const.

Is it possible in Eigen to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two immediate options:

1. Use the `mutable` keyword for the members that need to change in `const` methods (i.e. your temporary buffers). This keyword makes sense where observable behavior of your class *is* const, despite you needing to modify members. Examples include cached values, mutexes, or your buffers.
2. C++ is not perfectly strict with propagating `const`. A `const unique_ptr<T>` will return a (non-const) `T&` when dereferenced (because the const says "you can't change the pointer", not "you can't change the pointee"; this is the same with builtin pointers). You can similarly wrap your "real" sparse matrix class in something that pretends to be const but allows non-const access to the matrix if the STL smart pointers are insufficient. If you give it an appropriate name then it's not as terrible as it sounds.

I recommend option 1.

Comment: Thank you for answer! Do i understand correctly that first option is preferable because of "explicitness"?

Comment: It's just an appropriate place to use `mutable`, it is simply idiomatic. The second feels a lot like a hack (because it _is_ circumventing the original intent of the interface entirely). I'm still suggesting it because sometimes `mutable` is not the "correct"/idiomatic solution.